# Android-client server application in the same device

Tags: android, client

Can i create an application that contains the client and server in the same device?
if it's possible ,can someone give some real android application examples.
And thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, you needs is possible the android bluetooth chat is working on same concept just try this link [link](http://myandroidappdevelop.blogspot.in/2013/05/bluetooth-chat-example.html) and android sdk also had the bluetooth chat app example

Comment: Hi ,well if ther is the bluetooth chat app example ,could be also the same example with Wifi ?

Comment: sorry,u have to find out :)

Comment: hey cill out, anyhow all the best :)

Comment: well i found that it's possible to have a communication between client and a server using wifi with Socket.And now my question is ,could i do this work in the SAME device .The device will play the role of client and server .The client will send data (upload ) ,then the server will download that data, I know it's quite diffucult to explain :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes can make `Client-Server` app in same device using `JAVA Servlet`. Refer this github project [Android HTTP Server](https://github.com/piotrpolak/android-http-server)

Small but powerful multithreaded web server written completely in `Java SE` and then ported to Android.

A complete zero-dependency implementation of a web server and a servlet container in Java with a sample Android application.